# nodejs .net modules or how to consume C# component in nodejs

Tags: .net, node.js, owin

is there any node modules available to utilize the existing dot net components.

OWIN - Hosting can be done on node.  Does is it have any windows OS dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried it but Edge.js might be what you're looking for. http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge

The documentation says

> Edge.js connects
>
> 30k+ npm modules with 11k+ nuget packages
>
> JavaScript with C#, F#, Python, and PowerShell
>
> loose typing with strong typing
>
> IO-bound single threaded with CPU-bound multi-threaded
>
> cool with awesome
>   in one process

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host your OWIN components on node.js, check out connect-owin npm package:

https://github.com/bbaia/connect-owin

https://github.com/bbaia/connect-owin-samples

connect-owin depends on edge.js